# PHP Replace images from string

Tags: php, replace, preg-match

I have some code to get all instances of html IMG code from `$string`.

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$string, $result);
foreach ($result as $img) {
    if ($img) { echo $img[0]; }
    }
```

However I want to work with each image (check its dimensions etc) then replace it in the original `$string`

How can I insert/replace it back where it was originally found?

Comment: Do you mean back in that database or back into `$img`?

Comment: I think (s)he means back into `$string`

Comment: You could do `$string = str_replace($img[0], 'your replacement', $string)`

Comment: There is something called DOM (DOMDocument in PHP) which will make the job a lot easier and safer.  Replacing text in a string doesn't always work as you would expect.